# How can I build LLVM and use LLVM api in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I want to followe the LLVM tutorial to implement my toy compiler. However, I try many times to cmake and build from LLVM source but only fail to make the sample codes compiled.

For example, it comes to the error that "llvm/IR/Attributes.inc": No such file or directory.

So how can I fix the errors and begin to use LLVM api?

Comment: Which cmake generator are you using?